# How do I promote a collaborator in parse.com to an administrator so they can add other collaborators?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm currently working on a parse.com project and I want another collaborator to be able to add additional collaborators to the project. I'm not quite sure how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't promote them to be an admin.

Answer (score 0):

Only the main account can add additional collaborators per Pasre's website.
https://parse.com/plans/faq

> How do I share access to my app? Can multiple people collaborate on my
>   app?
>   You may share access to one app with one or more collaborators.
>   Each collaborator should sign up for a Parse account individually if
>   they don't have one yet. You can then invite them to collaborate on
>   your app from the Collaborators panel in your app's Settings. You as
>   the app owner will remain responsible for any charges your app may
>   incur. Collaborators will share the same level of access that an app
>   owner has, but they will not be able to delete the app or add more
>   collaborators.

Good luck.